# How to get value of hidden input with simple html dom?

Tags: php

I have these inputs:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="productBasePrice" value="1200.0000">
 <input type="hidden" id="productFinalPrice" value="420.0000">
```

I want to get the value of productBasePrice ID

I am trying this:

```
echo $html->find("input[id$='productBasePrice']",0)->plaintext;
```

but no success, it's returning blank!

Comment: you are using php, why don't you post the value and get it on server? using form field name

Comment: This inputs are on another domain and I use simple html dom to get html informations

Comment: can't even use jquery or js?

Answer (score 0):

- Use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in PHP to parse the HTML DOM.
- To get the value of an element by ID, use [getElementById()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) method.
- Once retrieved, use [getAttribute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method of the returned [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) to get the value inside the attribute `value`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


$dom_doc = new DOMDocument();
$dom_doc->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="productBasePrice" value="1200.0000" />
        <input type="hidden" id="productFinalPrice"  value="420.0000" />
    </body>
</html>');

echo $dom_doc->getElementById('productBasePrice')->getAttribute('value');
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/U1IdT

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need to be done with simple html dom

Comment: @Catalin Any specific reason to not use DOMDocument that PHP provides?

Comment: because I use html source code from another website

Comment: @Catalin You can use DOMDocument to parse HTML source code from other website as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    // Load from a string
    $html->load('<html><body><input type="hidden" id="productBasePrice" value="1200.0000"><input type="hidden" id="productFinalPrice" value="420.0000"></body></html>');

    // Get value of input values based on ID
    foreach($html->find('input[id="productBasePrice"]') as $input) 
    {
        echo $input->value.'<br />';
    }
?>
```